# Zend Framework: How to query from select/join

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I have 2 table "activity" and "activity_comment" connected together by column "activity_id".
[image]
[image]
I wanna count "flag" column by each value in it.
Like how many "flag"="challenge" and how many "flag"="risk" in the "activity_comment" table.
My current query:

```
$select = $db->select()->from(array('main_table' => $prefixTable . '_activity'))
->joinLeft(array('comment_table' => $prefixTable . '_activity_comment'), 'main_table.activity_id = comment_table.activity_id', array('comment_flag' => '(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(comment_table.flag) FROM ' . $prefixTable . '_activity_comment as comment_table WHERE comment_table.flag = "challenge") <> 0 THEN COUNT(comment_table.flag) ELSE 0 END)'));
```

[image]
But it throw out an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(comment_table.flag) FROM 17_activity_comment' in 'field list'

Sound like i can't use another query inside a select.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You'd like something like `activity_id, flag, count`, right? Or just `flag, count`?

Comment: @Ermenegildo sure i could need them all or just flag, count is good enough.

Comment: ah nvm, i found a way, its use query to create temp table, then left join through it.